# How to send data about boolean field from template to django views by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, checkbox

is there any possibility to send form values from template to db by jQuery? I want to change boolean value in checkbox and save it in model and sent this information by jQuery to view.

In my template I've got this:

```
<form id="foodForm" action="{% url 'foods:choose_diet' %}" method="post" role="form">  
    <div id="green-check" class="checkbox">
        <input id="green_check"  {% if diet.is_green %} checked {% endif %} type="checkbox" data-symbol="green-check"/>
        <label> Diet choose </label> 
    </div>
</form>
```

is_green is a boolean field in Diet model with default = False. After check the checkbox it change on True, but how can do this in views?

Answer (score 0):

You need a change listener on the checkbox that triggers an AJAX submit of the form:

To get you started (this is a very condensed version, check the jquery documentation for more):

```
$('#green_check').on('change', $('form#foodForm').submit);
```

Prevent default handling of submit:

```
$('form#foodForm').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        succes: function(data) {
            // this is what your view returns which should be either
            // - an html snippet
            // - json (returned via JSONResponse)
        },
        error: ...
    });
});
```